# Determining most register hungry part of kernel

Tags: optimization, cuda, opencl, gpgpu, cpu-registers

when I get a kernel using too many registers there are basically 3 options I can do:

1. leave the kernel as it is, which results in low occupancy
2. set compiler to use lower number of registers, spilling them, causing worse performance
3. rewrite the kernel

For option 3, I'd like to know which part of the kernel needs the maximum number of registers. Is there any tool or technique allowing me to identify this part? Reading through the PTX code (I develop on NVidia) is not helpful, the registers have various high numbers and to be honest, the best I can do is to identify which part of the assembly code maps to which part of the C code.

Just commenting out some code is not much a way to go - for example, I noticed that if I just put the code into loop, the number of registers raises dramatically, not only by one for the loop control variable. I personally suspect the NVidia compiler from imperfect variable liveness analysis, but of course I cannot do much with that :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on NVidia hardware, you can pass -cl-nv-verbose compile option to clBuildProgram then clGetProgramInfo CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES to get human readable text about the compile. In there it will say the number of registers it uses. Note that NVidia caches compiles and it only produces that register info when the kernel source actually changes, so you may want to inject some superfluous change in the source code to force it to do the full analysis.

If you're running on AMD hardware, just set the environment variable GPU_DUMP_DEVICE_KERNEL=1. It will produce a text file of the IL during the compile. Not sure it explicitly says the number of registers used, but it's what is equivalent to the NVidia technique above.

When looking at that output (at least on nvidia), you'll find that it seems to use an infinite number of registers (if you go by the register numbers). In reality, it does a flow analysis and actually reuses registers in a way that is not at all obvious when looking at the IL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough question in any language, and there's probably not one correct answer.  But here are some things to think about:

- Look for the code in the "deepest" scope you can find, keeping in mind that most functions are probably inlined by your OpenCL compiler.  Count the variables used in this scope, and walk up the containing scopes.  In each containing scope, count variables that are used both before and after the inner scope.  These are potentially live while the inner scope executes.  This process could help you account for the live registers at a particular part of the program.
- Try to take variables that "span" deep scopes and make them not span the scope if possible.  For example, if you have something like this:

  ```
  int i = func1();
  int j = func2();  // perhaps lots of live registers here
  int k = func3(i,j);
  ```

  you could try to reorder the first two lines if func2 has lots of live registers.  That would remove i from the set of live registers while func2 is running.  This is a trivial pattern, of course, but hopefully it's illustrative.
- Think about getting rid of variables that just keep around the results of simple computations.  You might be able to recompute these when you need them.  For example, if you have something like int i = get_local_id(0) you might be able to just use get_local_id(0) wherever you would have used i.
- Think about getting rid of variables that are keeping around values stored in memory.

Without good tools for this kind of thing, it ends up being more art than science.  But hopefully some of this is helpful.

Comment: Well, I know this "theory", but I was rather looking for the good tools. I am not sure how many optimizations does the compiler use, but a good compiler can change the code a lot. For example, with loop unwinding (which are surely done) the number of registers used raises over the number of variables.